# Emails from my domain treated as spam by Gmail and Outlook

Tags: email, dns, gmail, spam-prevention, email-filter

I know that this question asked multiple times before but I have a little bit different situation.

**In Brief:**

I have reverse DNS, PTR records, SPF records, DKIM 1024-bit key, IP not blacklisted, message content not spam characteristics.

Emails delivered to inbox on Yahoo and AOL. but, they go to spam / junk on Gmail and Outlook.

---

**In details:**

Reverse DNS checked:

```
host 12.34.56.789
```

**Note:** *This IP isn't the real IP of the server.*

Output:

```
789.56.34.12.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer mydomain.com.
```

SPF records:

```
"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:12.34.56.789 -all"
```

SPF Checked by [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx):

[image]

DKIM Checked by [protodave](http://www.protodave.com/tools/dkim-key-checker/):

[image]

IP blacklist test checked by [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx): **Passed All**

Yahoo and AOL works fine, but Gmail and Outlook mark emails as spam.

I contacted the gmail team couple of times but they didn't respond for over 10 days.

I'm sending plain text, no html codes.

No bulk emails, no newsletter.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? Am I missing something? Appreciate any suggestions.

---

**Further Details (Email Header):**

```
Delivered-To: myemail@gmail.com
Received: by 10.202.86.147 with SMTP id k141dre728845oib;
        Tue, 4 Nov 2014 23:26:11 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.170.225.135 with SMTP id r129mr14547913ykf.104.1412359371276;
        Tue, 04 Nov 2014 23:26:11 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <sales@mydomain.com>
Received: from hostname.mydomain.com (mydomain.com. [12.34.56.789])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id v44si1322694yhv.201.2014.11.04.23.26.10
        for <myemail@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 04 Nov 2014 23:26:10 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of sales@mydomain.com designates 12.34.56.789 as permitted sender) client-ip=12.34.56.789;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of sales@mydomain.com designates 12.34.56.789 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=sales@mydomain.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mydomain.com; s=default;
    h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version:Message-ID:Subject:From:To:Date; bh=lr4CWwmBPE2kmCn+bQZxuDI83bEg03tG585GFUO9nbM=;
    b=gsXWNQFoHVg/98V1pfGYpqCmzeKE6BK/93Zy/vT61ySaEdeLrTl9TW6Ca8C/nh+1C19vRfQbv716c+Q2gDEfAXw5/S8mEPjoBAlF96bXfLUuIpnY2OLLELAobd+VkpYaeOpAVnVMUDoie5M+m+lp98btL31BXWOKfPCCJ8UHZ5Q=;
Received: from localhost ([::1]:36366 helo=www.mydomain.com)
    by hostname.mydomain.com with esmtpsa (TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256)
    (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <sales@mydomain.com>)
    id 1Xluyo-00032t-Az
    for myemail@gmail.com; Wed, 05 Nov 2014 02:26:10 -0500
Date: Wed, 5 Nov 2014 02:26:10 -0500
X-Priority: 3
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_73e9fc0155fddc64feb30693a746sd5c"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - hostname.mydomain.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - mydomain.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: hostname.mydomain.com: authenticated_id: sales@mydomain.com

--b1_73e9fc0155fddc64feb30693a746sd5c
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Comment: Mizac, as per the above comment, this will likely be closed as it's off topic. However, doens't mean we can't help until then :) ... Is this your own SMTP server? Does the eamil address (from@) matter (does it succeed if you send from from2@)? Do you have another email account you can send via the SMTP server?

Comment: I cant imagin how the ip 12.34.56.789 should work. Please explain it.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have a VPS with cPanel/WHM installed. I send emails from my domain (e.g. info@mydomain.com), emails delivered on Yahoo and AOL in inbox but delivered to spam folder on Gmail and Outlook. I have root access, should I change the SMTP port? It is 25 on my vps. Also, the IP I mentioned above isn't the actual IP of my server, I just used it as an example. Thanks :) @Dave

Comment: It's not the real server's IP address, I used a random number in the question only. I'm sorry didn't clarify that. But the emails works fine and delivered. The issue that they deliver in spam folder of Gmail and Outlook. It works fine with Yahoo and AOL. @IvanViktorovic

Comment: Send via a different account. Buy a new domain, use the same VPS to send the mail to see if the issue is the domain (unlikely) or something else. Or, create a new email account. THhe port should make no difference. I assume you have reverse look up sorted?